# Sending arguments to Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, cmd, mstest

I am not able to pass some parameters to my Dev cmd prompt for vs, I can do it with the classic cmd but not with this one. And I need it because I want to execute CodedUITests from an executable.

This is what my code looks like:

```
String Path = @"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Visual Studio 2012\Visual Studio Tools\Developer Command Prompt for VS2012.lnk";

ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo();
proc.FileName = Path;
proc.UseShellExecute = true;
proc.Arguments =  @"/c MSTest/h";
Process.Start(proc);
```

It starts, but no args are inserted,what am I doing wrong ?

EDIT 1 - None of these are working

```
Process.Start(Path, @"/c "+"MSTest/h"); - err : invalid path - in dev cmd prompt
```

OR

```
Process.Start(Path, @"/c ""MSTest/h"); -  err: invalid path - in dev cmd prompt
```

OR

```
Process.Start(Path, @"/c MSTest/h"); - nothing
```

OR

```
Process.Start(Path, "/c MSTest/h"); -nothing
```

OR

```
Process.Start(Path,  "MSTest/h");  -nothing
```

EDIT 2 - This is how my final code looks like, partially working, dev cmd starting, but no way to parse args into it because any args I pass they go straight to cmd not to dev-cmd

```
// ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", @"%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat""");
            ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", @"%comspec% /k ""C:\Users\butoiu.edward\Desktop\VsDevCmd1.bat");            
            procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
           // procStartInfo.Arguments = "/k MSTest";
            Process proc = new Process();

            proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
            proc.Start();


            proc.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: You should be able to use Process.Start (<command>, <argument>) like : Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "google.com");

Comment: have a look over my thread, I don't understand why's Developer CMD so special that it won't work...

Comment: Developer Command Prompt for VS2012 is just a shortcut (".lnk") to another program. You need to point to the actual command that the shortcut points to. Currently in VS2022 that is the VsDevCmd.bat file. Then you need to check whether that batch file can actually accept the arguments that you want to pass it, or you could add your command to the end of the batch file.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this way?

```
    void OpenWithArguments()
    {
        Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "www.northwindtraders.com");
        Process.Start("path to exe", "argument");
    }
```

-- `FMI` [MSDN LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments(v=vs.110).aspx)

### Update:

I assume it will work this way... but not sure

Open sys default cmd prompt.. and give first param as batch file path (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat`) and give a space and add next attribute.

```
Process.Start("Path to EXE", "arg1 arg2")
```

Comment: @ExtremeSwat What are you trying there? are you trying to open Cmd promt?

Comment: No, I am trying to open Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio.
The only way to launch tests outside of VS is throughout Developer Command Prompt

Comment: VS Command Prompt also target to default cmd prompt.. But on load it will execute a special batch file so that it can load .net environment..

Comment: VsDevCmd.bat, so I won't be able to / no way of throwing arguments to this kind of command prompt ? This was my last solution for test running

Comment: I shall come back with an answer in about 10 hours, not at my work's PC right now. Thanks

Comment: Your answer gave me some insight but didn't solve my issue because the problem lies upon the way I pass these parameters and to whom.
I start cmd and pass as a parameter the start of that bat tool (dev tool cmd prompt), but if I pass for example MSTest/h as a second parameter it won't work because it will be sent to cmd, not to developer cmd. The only possible way(I guess ) is to make my own batch. Thanks for the answer. also check my thread edit

Answer (score 0):

lnk" file it is actually a link of visual studio cmd prompt. Instead of this location you try original file located at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"

```
String Path = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat";

ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo();
proc.FileName = Path;
proc.UseShellExecute = true;
proc.Arguments =  @"/c MSTest/h";
Process.Start(proc);
```

I hope this will help you.