# Run Console application under developer command prompt

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, console-application

I have a Console app that runs some actions on a C# solution using `csc.exe`, `msbuild.exe` and `tf.exe`.
I would like to run my app in the context of the `Visual Studio developer command prompt` (without actually make the user open it) since it automatically sets up the paths for the files above thus reducing the need to search for them and store the paths locally for each user.
How can I run my console app under the developer command prompt?

Comment: May be you can check these- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34945164/open-visual-studio-command-prompt-from-c-sharp-code, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25286082/sending-arguments-to-developer-command-prompt-for-visual-studio and http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/want-to-run-command-in-vs-command-promt-from-c-sharpnet-or-vb-net

Comment: Surely you just run the vsdevcmd.bat file from a process in your app?

Comment: These solutions doesn't let me use the environment variables set by the developer command prompt in the context of my app.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a batch file like so:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat" && echo %FrameworkDir%
```

This sets up the environment, then echoes the value of one of the variables set up. Just replace the `echo` command with your own command.